# What policy implication would "non-whites-only space" generate?

Tags: united-states, policy, barack-obama

A group of students in Michigan is demanding a "non-whites-only" space so they can organize on social justice, specifically for people of color; (See [here](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4254658/Michigan-college-students-demand-non-whites-space.html)).

The group's stated goal is to "fight against the oppression and hateful acts that try to destroy us and our community."

Given the nationwide trend towards self-segregation, it would be interesting to see how governments / administrations at all levels form policies to accommodate such demands.

> Q1: what policy implications, if any, would "non-whites-only space" generate?
>
> Q2: what does that mean for people with mixed racial heritage? Like half-white / half-black (President Obama) or whites with 1/32nd indian (Senator Warren)?

Comment: "Given the nationwide trend towards self-segregation" = what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is clear discrimination based on race, so I doubt it will stand if any white person tries to enter that facility.

The government might need to send state troopers to enforce the right of anyone to enter the facility, though.

Comment: While the US has federal protections against certain types of discrimination, it would be helpful if you added references indicating under which US or state law this would be illegal. After all, it's quite common for there to be spaces which are restricted on other features like gender (you may be familiar with gender-based bathrooms). Can you name a case where race-based spaces in education were banned or under which provisions this may be illegal?

Comment: But the US DOES allow racial discrimination given a good reason. For example, the US allows affirmative action which makes race a factor in decisions as compensation for minorities.